# Scrapy crawled but not scraped

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping data from [this website](https://www.openingstijden.nl/) and have found their ajax source links to have the format
`f"https://www.openingstijden.nl/ajax-resultaten/?page={page_num}&business_id={business_id}&no-limit=1"` with page_num being page number and business id being the id of the store. Example: https://www.openingstijden.nl/ajax-resultaten/?page=20&business_id=5688&no-limit=1.

This is my code:

```
class SupermarketScraper(scrapy.Spider):
name = "supermarkets"

def __init__(self):
    self.images = ast.literal_eval(pkg_resources.read_text(resources, 'times.json'))
    self.geodata = set()
    sentry_sdk.init(dsn=SENTRY_SDK_DSN)
    self.session = requests.Session()

def start_requests(self):
    b_ids = ['5688'] #[item['b_id'] for item in business_ids]
    page_num = 1
    for b_id in b_ids:
        url = f'https://www.openingstijden.nl/ajax-resultaten/?page={page_num}&business_id={b_id}&no-limit=1'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, cb_kwargs=dict(b_id=b_id, page_num=page_num))
            
def parse(self, response, b_id, page_num):
    items = response.css('li')
    if items: 
        for item in items:
            link = item.css('a.btn::attr(href)').get()
            geodata = item.css('li::attr(data-geo)').get().split(',')
            if (geodata[0], geodata[1]) not in self.geodata:
                self.geodata.add((geodata[0], geodata[1]))
            else:
                return

            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_store, cb_kwargs=dict(geodata=geodata, b_id=b_id, page_num=page_num))

        new_url = f'http://www.openingstijden.nl/ajax-resultaten/?page={page_num+1}&business_id={b_id}&no-limit=1'
        yield response.follow(new_url, callback=self.parse, cb_kwargs=dict(b_id=b_id, page_num=page_num+1))

def parse_store(self, response, geodata, b_id, page_num):
    name = response.css('#est-name::text')[0].get()
    location = response.css('span.locate span::text').getall()
    street, postal_code, city = location[0:3]

    location = LocationItem()
    location['street'] = street
    location['postal_code'] = postal_code
    location['city'] = city
    location['lat'] = geodata[0]
    location['lng'] = geodata[1]

    item = SupermarketItem()
    item['business_id'] = b_id
    item['name'] = name
    item['location'] = location
    item['page_num'] = page_num
    yield item
```

The code runs without error, however, it does not scrape all the data and some pages appear to be crawled but no data were scraped, like this:

```
2020-11-11 09:23:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.openingstijden.nl/Albert-Heijn/Den-Haag/Prinses-Beatrixlaan-590/> (referer: https://www.openingstijden.nl/ajax-resultaten/?page=20&business_id=5688&no-limit=1)
2020-11-11 09:23:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.openingstijden.nl/Albert-Heijn/De-Meern/Mereveldplein-13/> (referer: https://www.openingstijden.nl/ajax-resultaten/?page=20&business_id=5688&no-limit=1)
2020-11-11 09:23:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.openingstijden.nl/Albert-Heijn/Voorschoten/Schoolstraat-1/> (referer: https://www.openingstijden.nl/ajax-resultaten/?page=20&business_id=5688&no-limit=1)
2020-11-11 09:23:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.openingstijden.nl/Albert-Heijn/Den-Haag/Stationsplein-75/> (referer: https://www.openingstijden.nl/ajax-resultaten/?page=20&business_id=5688&no-limit=1)
2020-11-11 09:23:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.openingstijden.nl/Albert-Heijn/Brielle/Thoelaverweg-2/> (referer: https://www.openingstijden.nl/ajax-resultaten/?page=20&business_id=5688&no-limit=1)
2020-11-11 09:23:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.openingstijden.nl/Albert-Heijn/Oude-Tonge/Dabbehof-34/> (referer: https://www.openingstijden.nl/ajax-resultaten/?page=20&business_id=5688&no-limit=1)
2020-11-11 09:23:55 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.openingstijden.nl/Albert-Heijn/Den-Haag/Johanna-Westerdijkplein-64/>
{'business_id': '5688',
 'location': {'city': 'Den Haag',
 'lat': '52.0674',
 'lng': '4.32342',
 'postal_code': '2521EN',
 'street': 'Johanna Westerdijkplein 64'},
 'name': 'Albert Heijn',
 'page_num': 20}
```

The last link was properly scraped, however, all the previous links were crawled but nothing returned. No error were thrown and the spider closed without scraping all data.

I've tried changing my USER_AGENT to `USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36'` but it didnt work. All these pages also have identical web structure and can be scraped individually at ease.

Is the server actively blocking scraper? Why are these urls' data missed by the scraper?

Comment: If it says “crawled”, your callback got called with the corresponding response. You can log the response content to find out what you are getting from the server as response, and see if it matches your expectations.

Comment: When I log the response content, it does match my expectation. Crawling these missed urls individually returns exactly what I want. So the scraper just skipped them for unclear reason

Comment: @pa-nguyen, did you find a solution? I have the same issue